# CKeditor 4.4 not saving attributes

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have CKeditor 4.4 and the image plugin is not saving the extra attributes.

When I insert an image I get this code

```
<img 147px="" alt="" px=""  src="http://localhost/mysite/5cbe989e2d7de872997fff3fe894aa0d.png" />
```

I have also set the config like so; note the `allowedContent:true`,

Im also using jQuery and the jQuery adapter, every other feature works but this.

```
$('textarea.wysiwyg').ckeditor({
    toolbar: [
        ['Maximize'],
        ['Format', 'FontSize'],         
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline','-','StrikeThrough'],
        ['Source']                      
      ],
    width : '99%',
    height : 100,
    dialog_backgroundCoverColor : '#000',
    defaultLanguage : 'en',
    language : 'en',
    allowedContent : true,                  
});
```

Comment: Those are invalid HTML5 attributes... are you sure CKEditor creates them?

Comment: yes it is what ckeditor produces, After I create an image I click on source to view it and thats what its creating

Comment: You click on source view? You toolbar doesn't have that button, so I don't know how you're really viewing it

Comment: Ahh sorry, the other instance of CKeditor I have has the source button, but same thing happens. I will add the source button to the above example

Comment: It does not look like something produced by CKEditor. Maybe your backed alters this HTML? A live example would help us a lot (like JSFiddle).

Comment: Good idea, I will produce the code and create a fiddle.